# in C# Generics this is impossible?

Tags: c#, generics

```
class Bar
{
    static public Bar Instance { get { return null; /*return instance*/ } }
}

private void Foo<T>() where T : Bar
{
    T getInstace = T.Instance;
}
```

this is error, but need get Instance.

this have a solution?

thank

++

```
class Bar<T>
{
    static public T Instance { get { return default(T); /*return instance*/ } }
}

class BarChild : Bar<BarChild>
{ 
    public void Func(){}
}

private T Foo<T>() where T : Bar<T>
{
    return T.Instance;
}

private void Example()
{
    Foo<BarChild>().Func();
}
```

I would like to be doing this you know.
but, "T.Instance" is error..

Comment: What's the point? Since you pass no parameters to `Foo`, the difference between `Foo<Bar>()` and `Foo(Bar.Instance)` is minimal.

Comment: Why not just pass in the T type? Or have some factory method?

Comment: There isn't a valid type for `Instance` which would be valid for all types `T`.   `Bar` would need to be generic. Though it's not entirely clear what you want, so there may be other alternatives.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's wrong with `class Foo<T> { Bar instance = T.Instance; }` or `class Foo<T> : where T : new() { static T instance = new T(); }`? This question seems to have [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it.

Comment: Added detailed problem in question. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually are close to doing what you want. Some might consider this an abuse of the type system. I consider it a weakness of the language. The problem you are trying to solve is that you want to access a static member of a generic class, whose type is the type of the class, not a hardcoded type. This *is* possible.

```
class Base<T> where T : Base<T> {
    public static T SomeMethod() { ... }
}

class Derived : Base<Derived> {

}

public void Main() {
    Derived d = Derived.SomeMethod();  // correctly returns an object of type Derived, even though method is defined in base class
}
```

This is a variation on the CRTP from C++.

So this is not really virtual or dynamic dispatch. The only reason you get this behavior with statics is because of the generics. The types are all known at compile-time. It can still be useful in class hierarchies where you want the derived type to be able to use base type methods as if they are the derived type's methods. Or, put another way, where you can make templatized methods in the base class that work in the derived class as if they were declared there. One place you might want to use it is in a `Clone()` method that returns the right type. You could declare it as `public abstract T Clone()` in the base class and it would have the right return type in derived classes.

EDIT: updated code to do everything the OP wants:

```
public class Base<T>
    where T : Base<T>, new() {
    public static T Instance {
        get {
            return new T();
        }
    }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived> {
    public void SomeFunc() {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeFunc()");
    }
}

// in other code

private T Foo<T>() where T : Base<T>, new() {
    // note that we can't just use T directly here, but that's okay, because we know that T is always going to be at least a Base<T>
    return Base<T>.Instance;
}

private void Example() {
    // the type of Base<Derived>.Instance is Derived, so you can call Func() on it
    Base<Derived>.Instance.SomeFunc();

    // can also do this:
    Foo<Derived>().SomeFunc();
}
```

Comment: I there is a need for Foo<BarChild>().Func();
but, not possible.

Comment: @Lim: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @@siride // I just wanted to call Foo <BarChild> (). Func (); but T.Instance; It was not possible to use it due to a compilation error. Now that I know how to do Reflection, I solved it. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @Lim: you don't need to use reflection for this. See my updated answer.

Comment: When I checked it, I did not really need Reflection. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this boils down to a fundamental misunderstanding of the `static` keyword. It is NOT a mechanism for sharing members across instances, it is a way to inform the compiler that it can allocate the member statically, i.e. without regard to the dynamic behaviour of the program at run-time.

Note that you cannot make a `static` member `virtual`, which means that you can't override it in a subclass. Since subclassing is a static process, you can reference static members of a parent class as if they were inherited, because the compiler can work out where the member is defined.

Even if what you're describing were syntactically legal, there would be no way for `T.Instance` to refer to anything other than `Bar.Instance`.

Comment: "It is NOT a mechanism for sharing members across instances" --- WAT

Comment: The `static` keyword dates back long before classes in C#. It so happens that it serves this purpose quite nicely, but that's not its primary purpose.

Comment: The primary purpose of a programming language - is to provide facilities to solve tasks, not just to "generate a binary that can allocate something statically". Not sure how the fact that runtime allocates static members on demand proves your point either.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Virtual methods work by dispatching on the run-time type of an object, not the static type of the reference. You cannot know statically which override of a virtual method will be called at run-time, that's what makes virtual methods powerful. Conversely you can always know statically what code will be invoked by a call to a static method precisely because it's static. It's not possible to override a static member because that goes against the very definition of static.

Comment: It is possible to do this. See my answer. But you are correct to note that this is *not* the same as virtual methods and dynamic dispatch. It's static dispatch through an inheritance hierarchy, enabled by generics. There's value for that, but it's not the same thing.